# Дек. улучшение кода по замечаниям ревьюера

Tags: python, алгоритм

*Как можно реализовать методы проверки полноты пустоты, а также исправить исключения?*
Замечания написал комментарием в коде, в тех местах, где мне нужно исправить. Не могу додуматься как сделать и внедрить это всё в код. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

**Задание:**
Гоша реализовал структуру данных Дек, максимальный размер которого определяется заданным числом. Методы push_back(x), push_front(x), pop_back(), pop_front() работали корректно. Но, если в деке было много элементов, программа работала очень долго. Дело в том, что не все операции выполнялись за O(1). Помогите Гоше! Напишите эффективную реализацию.

**Внимание: при реализации нельзя использовать связный список.**

**Формат ввода**

В первой строке записано количество команд n — целое число, не превосходящее 5000. Во второй строке записано число m — максимальный размер дека. Он не превосходит 1000. В следующих n строках записана одна из команд:

*push_back(value)* – добавить элемент в конец дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
*push_front(value)* – добавить элемент в начало дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
*pop_front()* – вывести первый элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».
*pop_back()* – вывести последний элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».
Value — целое число, по модулю не превосходящее 1000.

**Формат вывода**

Выведите результат выполнения каждой команды на отдельной строке. Для успешных запросов push_back(x) и push_front(x) ничего выводить не надо.

**Пример**

**Ввод:**

4

4
push_front 861

push_front -819

pop_back

pop_back

**Вывод:**

861

-819

**Мой код:**

```
class Deque:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self.__queue = [None] * max_size
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.size = 0
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = 0

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    def push_back(self, value):
        if self.size == self.max_size:  # Не помешают методы для проверки полноты/пустоты.
            return 'error' # Гибче и идиоматичнее для ошибок кидать исключения, а обрабатывать их снаружи.

        self.__queue[self.tail] = value
        self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.max_size
        self.size += 1

    def push_front(self, value):
        if self.size == self.max_size:
            return 'error'
        self.__queue[self.head - 1] = value
        self.head = (self.head - 1) % self.max_size
        self.size += 1

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        item = self.__queue[self.head]
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.max_size
        self.size -= 1
        return item

    def pop_back(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        item = self.__queue[self.tail - 1]
        self.tail = (self.tail - 1) % self.max_size
        self.size -= 1
        return item


def main():
    count = int(input())
    size = int(input())
    queue = Deque(size)

    commands = {
        'push_back': queue.push_back,
        'push_front': queue.push_front,
        'pop_front': queue.pop_front,
        'pop_back': queue.pop_back,
    }

    for _ in range(count):
        command = input()
        operation, *value = command.split()

        if value:
            try:
                result = commands[operation](*value)
                if result is not None:
                    print(result)
            except OverflowError:  # Этого друга уже нет.

                print('error')
        else:
            try:
                result = commands[operation]()
                print(result)

            except IndexError:
                print('error')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по замечаниям вам нужно проверку `if self.size == self.max_size:` обернуть в метод, подобно методу `is_empty()` и вместо `return 'error'` использовать `raise IndexError('Дек переполнен')`